# Difference between 'antico', 'arcaico' and 'disusato' as categories in Italian dictionaries

Tags: word-usage, difference

Using Italian dictionaries, I have noticed that dated/archaic words are marked with different categories, and there are no explanations regarding any semantic differences.

For instance, *Lo Zingarelli* has three kinds of markings: *1. ant. (antico), 2. disus. (disusato), 3. † (parola o accezione arcaica)*. These are the explanations given in the preface to the dictionary. Browsing Lo Zingarelli, I can find the *ant.* note only in etymological explanations:

> accapigliàrsi [comp. di a- (2) e capegli, forma ***ant.*** di capelli ☼ 1266]

> assìṣa [***ant.*** fr. assise ‘uniforme’, da asseoir ‘stabilire’, dal lat. parl. *assedēre, per il classico assidēre ☼ 1308]

The other two are found directly in word explanations. For instance:

> àbaco 3 (***disus.***) arte del calcolo, aritmetica

> accòllo 2 (***disus.***) appalto

And:

> riconoscènza 2 **†** rimorso

> indirìzzo 4 **†** avviamento | impostazione

Furthermore, other dictionaries even do not provide a complete list of abbreviations. But from what I noticed, I can say the the *Grande Dizionario Italiano* by *Gabrielli Aldo* has only one kind of category, namely *ant. (antico)*:

> riconoscenza 2 ***ant.*** Riconoscimento, consapevolezza

Otherwise the *Grande Dizionario Italiano* may use other notes where *Lo Zingarelli* uses *disus. (disusato)*:

> accollo ‖ ***raro*** Appalto

*Treccani* seems to use *ant. (antico)* only as well:

> riconoscènza 2. ***ant.*** Riconoscimento, consapevolezza

But in Treccani's *Sinonimi e Contrari disus. (disusato)* is used frequently:

> pastrano s. m. (***ant.*** pastrana s. f.) [prob. dal nome di un duca di Pastrana (città della prov. sp. di Guadalajara)], ***disus.*** - (abbigl.) [pesante indumento invernale per uomo, da portare sopra altri vestiti] ≈ cappotto, (***disus.***)

Finally, in *il Sabatini Coletti*, only *ant. (antico)* seems to be used as well:

> infingardo 2 ***ant.*** Bugiardo, falso

To summarize it all, I can state that there are noticeable differences between the *dated* and *archaic* categories in English dictionaries. As [Oxford](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507023300/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/old-fashioned-language) puts it:

> **Archaic**
> Words and expressions described as archaic are those which haven't been in everyday use for a century or more... You are unlikely to hear anyone using these terms in everyday conversation, or to come across them in modern writing, but you will encounter them in the literature of the past.

> **Dated**
> Words and expressions described as dated may still be used occasionally, especially by older people, but they are no longer used by most English speakers.

I suppose that this kind of difference might also exist in Italian dictionaries. Otherwise, probably *disus.* is used for historical names of objects which are no longer in use (but in the case of *abaco* as *arithmetic*, we can hardly speak of objects no longer in use: the designation itself seems to be *disusato*).

It is still unclear however, why *disus.* and † coexist in *Lo Zingarelli*, and whether they are both combined into *ant.* in other dictionaries.

So, my question is: how are these different markings interconnected in different dictionaries and which specific differences exist between them?

Comment: This is not an answer (even though it might be included in one), but you might find it interesting to have a look at the descriptions of the _marche d'uso_ in the dictionary directed by Tullio De Mauro, who was very meticulous about these aspects of lexicography: https://dizionario.internazionale.it/avvertenze/6 You might be interested especially in the LE, BU and OB markers.

Answer (score 7):

In the recent PhD thesis of Maurizio N. Barbi (in Italian)

[Neologismi e neosemie nel vocabolario
Zingarelli: un confronto sincronico tra la
Decima edizione (1970) e la ristampa della
Dodicesima edizione (2015)](https://uvidok.rcub.bg.ac.rs/bitstream/handle/123456789/2560/Doktorat.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

there are many useful explanations about the usage of markings in *Lo Zingarelli*.
The paper also cites many other sources that studied the use and evolution of such markings.

To summarize, the marking

*disusato (disus.), riferito a lemmi «caduti in disuso ma non arcaici»*

refers to terms that are not currently used, but yet cannot be defined as archaic.
These terms still have a correct meaning for most of contemporay Italians, while † (*arcaico*) or ant. (*antico*) currently might not be understood or might be associated with a wrong meaning.

Please also consider that *Lo Zingarelli* tends to introduce new markings and also to change their meaning or scope with the evolution of society and linguistic expression (Cannella, M. (2010). *Idee per diventare lessicografo*. Bologna: Zanichelli).
So the marking for a certain term might vary with time.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only thing that embarrasses me is why the other Italian dictionaries do not do it in the same manner as the Zingarelli does, and are using only _antico_ as a marking for both dated and archaic words (based on my own comparison of articles from the Zingarelli and Treccani, Sabatini Coletti, Garzanti, Hoepli (Aldo)). I mean that the Zingarelli's model is quite understandable and provides for the required differentiation. But the work with other dictionaries requires me using only my intuition (and the dates of their quotations) as a clue.